# Mapstruct : Use of context in source argument of @Mapping

Tags: mapstruct

When using multiple arguments in a @Mapper, it seems that the @Context arguments is unreachable

```java
public interface MyMapper {  
      @Mapping(target="target1", source="arg1.arg") //works
      @Mapping(target="target2", source="arg2") //works
      @Mapping(target="target3", source="arg2.arg") //works
      @Mapping(target="target2", source="context.arg") //NOT WORKING
      public MyTarget convert(Object arg1, Object arg2, @Context Object context);
      
}
```

I am trying to use and `expression=""` to work around it, but I can't get it to work.

Any suggestions?

I can see I am not the only one to ever wish this.
https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1280

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to pass a `@Context` and use it as source? Can you provide a bit more context?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I ran into the same scenario as I needed a `@Context` param to be able to pass to a nested mapping function, but also wanted to use it as a source in a `@Mapping`. I was able to achieve this using `expression` as follows:

```java
public interface MyMapper {

  @Mapping(target="target1", source="arg1")
  @Mapping(target="target2", source="arg2")
  @Mapping(target="target3", expression="java( contextArg )")
  public MyTarget convert(Object arg1, Object arg2, @Context Object contextArg);

}
```

Comment: Ok but no automatic enum conversion applied that way :(

Comment: How to do it if "target3" and "contextArg" are different types?

Answer (score 8):

To answer your second question:

```java
public interface MyMapper {

  @Mapping(target="target1", source="arg1.arg")
  @Mapping(target="target2", ignore = true ) // leave to after mapping 
  MyTarget convert(Object arg1, @Context Object context);

  @AfterMapping
  default void convert(Object arg1, @MappingTarget MyTarget target, @Context context) {
        target.setTarget2( convert (context) );
  } 

  // if you have multipe mappings, you could address them here
  @Mapping(target="target2", source="context.arg") 
  MyInnerTarget convert(Object arg1, Object context);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

By definition a `@Context` annotated object is not a source. It is context So you can't use it as `source` in the `@Mapping(target="target2", source="context.arg")`

Here is a related github issue with official answer: [github issue](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1280)

Comment: And how to achieve the desired behavior then?

Comment: remove the `@Context` and MapStruct will consider it as source object. By marking it `@Context` you essentially tell MapStruct to ignore the parameter for mapping, but pass it along in underlying method calls. Also, although MapStruct can handle multiple source arguments, it cannot call multiple source parameter methods to handle nested mappings. The API would become unpredictable and the selection mechanism would be come to unwieldy.

Comment: Your suggestion works if I need parameter in one place only. But if I need parameter on both layers I will have to do a `map(Source source, Param param, @Context Param param)` which makes no sense to me.. It would be much easier to not ignore context parameter for mapping..

Comment: The reason is stated in my comment above. However, you can stick to the `@Context` approach by delegation to a second method and an `@AfterMapping`.

Comment: Yes, I saw that approach somewhere in the official documentation. I just don't understand why creators don't want to include context in mapping.. Why they exclude it? Any ideas?

Comment: context == by definition context.. not a source parameter..  its sole purpose is being ignored by mapping

Comment: well, that's mapstruct team definition. context is something to be used as a context for all methods from the very first method where it is passed. Think of a batch job context or anything else. The very first class which has context passed as argument is more then welcome to read or put anything to context.

The mapstruct issue is that top level argument can't be made a context in downstream and context parameter can't be used as source in the first mapping.
I understand all the definitions and workarounds, but it doesn't feel right to me.
Thanks for a valuable discussion, appreciate that

Answer (score 1):

Not really clean, but it seems having the same object as source and context allows to use it both ways.

```java
  @Mapping(target="target1", source="arg1.arg")
  @Mapping(target="target2", source="arg2")
  @Mapping(target="target3", source="arg2.arg")
  @Mapping(target="target4", source="contextAsSource.arg") 
  public MyTarget convert(Object arg1, Object arg2, Object contextAsSource, @Context Object context);
```

Here contextAsSource and context are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way, is to define additional mapping method:

```java
public interface MyMapper {  
      @Mapping(target="target1", source="arg1.arg") 
      @Mapping(target="target3", source="arg2.arg")
      @Mapping(target="target2", source="arg3.arg") 
      MyTarget convert(Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3, @Context Object context);

      default MyTarget convert(Object arg1, Object arg2, Object context) {
         return convert(arg1, arg2, context, context);
      }
      
}
```